# CakePHP PDO prepare statement

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, pdo

I am using CakePHP 2.4.1 and I need to get direct access to PDO in order to pull a set of records from my MySQL DB, row by row.

This is the piece of code that I am using and that is generating the issue:

```
            // Get PDO access
    $this->_pdo = $this->Event->getDataSource();

    try {

        // Start transaction
        $this->_pdo->begin();

        // All the past events
        $stm = $this->_pdo->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `events` WHERE `stop_time` < '" . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "'");

        // Loop through the events
        if( $stm->execute() ) {
            while ($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                // ....
            }
        }

        // Commit transaction
        $this->_pdo->commit();

    } catch (Exception $e) {

        // Rollback transaction
        $this->_pdo->rollback();

        CakeLog::write('error', $e );
    }
```

However as soon as I launch the script I get back this error message

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined method Mysql::prepare()
```

but I have seen that this framework is supporting PDO and in particular the prepare() function.
[CakePHP PDO Documentation](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-PDO.html)

Any ideas?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Just for the record, all you are showing here can be accomplished using the [`DboSource` API](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DboSource.html) implemented by the `Mysql` datasource.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually the class you are using is http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-DataSource.html
No `prepare()` method there. Use this to get PDO

```
 $myPDO = $this->SomeModel->getDataSource()->getConnection();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to correct my code, using your solution and thus having full access to the PDO, _$this->_pdo->begin();_ must be changed with _$this->_pdo->beginTransaction();_